# CSS Display not applying

Tags: css

I am having trouble getting my display to apply in atom, my css display rules are not applying as well as float. My numerical rules are applying: ie margin-right: 25px; but not things like float right

Comment: please edit your question to include a [mcve] so that we can see the issue

Answer (score 0):

CSS priority is aplied as follows:

- Order in the code line
- Order in the css code
- !important declaration (what can override non specific actions)

Despite it's true that float & margin can be aplied together. This can give problems like in IE. What you can do is just use

```
margin: auto 25px auto auto;
```

Or

```
margin: auto;
margin-right: 20px;
```

More info see [this css doc](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp).

Float is basicly a tool that a lot coder use that are not aware how spacing in css work. I rarely use it unless I use flex-box that kinda bends the rules of align.

If this all still doesn't solve your problem (since you didn't really gave us a lot of information to work with). I suggest you take the direct solution by changing the item directly with an id styling like:

```
#thingy {
  float: right;
  margin: auto 25px auto auto;
}
```

and even more extreem:

```
#thingy {
  float: right;
  margin: auto 25px auto auto !important;
}
```